# Computing residuals from matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

This is my code for my matrix:

```r
physician < matrix(c(6, 22, 42, 23, 61, 127, 2, 3, 54, 1, 12, 43, 1, 12, 31), 
                   byrow = T, ncol = 3)

dimnames(physician) <- list(specialty = c("Internal", "Surgery", "Radiotherapy", 
                                          "Oncology", "Gynecology"), 
                            surgery = c("R", "CR", "C"))

physician
```

I would like to know how to compute residuals output for my matrix so I can infer nature of association between `specialty` and `surgery`. Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yes what do you exactly want?

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understood, what you want to do is compute the residuals from a Multinomial Logistic Regression of surgery on specialty. Here is a solution using the package         nnet :

```
  install.packages("nnet")
  library(nnet)
```

I transposed your matrice and created a column code_surgery :

```
  phy=data.frame(code_surgery=as.factor(c("R","CR","C")),data.frame(t(physician)))
```

take a look at your data frame :

```
  str(phy)
```

Then compute the regression :

```
  reg <- multinom(code_surgery ~ Internal + Surgery + Radiotherapy + Oncology + Gynecology, data=phy)
```

you can take a look at this regression using (the function took C as the reference group of code_surgery) :

```
  summary(reg)
```

I let you analyze and continue. Hint : you can get fitted values with

```
  reg$fitted.values
```

Hope it will help.